# How can I take each part of a file name and insert it into a table separately?

Tags: python, pandas, file

I've written a script that calculates a value for different genes in an organism. I would like to get out a csv file that has the columns 'Species ID', 'locus tag' and then the value itself.

I'm new to Python and I can't quite figure out how I would do this? An example of a file name is:

NC_000117.1+CT_001.txt

and each bit before and after the + is different. For reference, the bit before is the species ID and the bit after the + is the locus tag. I have around 6000 of these files and they're pretty small, so it shouldnt take too long to process!

This is my code so far:

```
import os
import io
import glob
import pandas as pd
import csv
work_dir = "User/..."
for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(work_dir, "*.txt")):
    with io.open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as dir:
        genome = dir.read()

    GC3_list = list()
    locus_list = list()

#calculates the total base number of each txt file
    total_base = len(genome)
    # print("Total no of bases:" + str(total_base))

#counts number of g and c bases at every 3rd position
    g = genome[::3].count('g')
    c = genome[::3].count('c')
    # print("Number of G bases:"+str(g))
    # print("Number of C bases:"+str(c))

#calculates final GC3 content in %
    GC3 = ((g+c)/total_base) * 100
    #print("GC3 content in % :" + str(GC3))
    GC3_list.append(GC3)

#loci names taken from file
    loci = os.path.basename(path).replace('.txt', "")
    locus_list.append(loci)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Locus tag':locus_list,
                  'GC3 %': GC3_list})

df.to_excel('output')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to split it at the '+' you can use `.split('+')` on your filename string.

Comment: Thanks! Would this work: loci = os.path.basename(path).split("+",[1])